# What is the correct way of storing .sql type files in a database?

Tags: sql, blob, storage

I am working in a system which gets reloaded frequently. When the system is reloaded a lot of files can be deleted or changed back to a previous stable build version (it's a dev environment). The only thing that doesn't get reloaded is a database.

I have been tasked with inserting and deleting .sql scripts into the environments so that if required someone can run them at a given time. Usually 2 weeks after the files have been added to the system.

Initially I had thought of creating a directory to keep the files, and make a table where one of the columns keeps the path to these .sql files. This would allow for someone to query the database and using the path they could execute a desired script. The problem is the environment constantly reloading which could result in losing files.

Am I correct in assuming that the correct way to approach this is to use BLOB datatype to store the .sql files? The database isn't reloaded so no files would be lost. I am new to SQL and I'm unsure what is the correct approach to this. Would Varchar also work? Is one datatype more efficient than the other?

Comment: `BLOB` store binary data (i.e. bytes). Maybe you want to store character data, that is a `CLOB`.

Comment: Sounds like source control to me...

Comment: Totally agree. SCMs (source control) tools are dedicated to solve this kind of issue. Try Git, Subversion (both free), or any other SCM your company has.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put SQL scripts in a SQL database, it doesn't feel right.
Sql Scripts usually go in a git repo, in order to be versioned and have better visibility.

Comment: These are single use scripts. They won't go through revisions, they will only be kept for a week then executed then discarded. They mostly hold insert statements.

Comment: Also it's not a simple case of using source control since anyone will be able to add .SQL scripts to the system to be executed at a later date. In this case the people that added the new files will have to commit the changes to repo.

Comment: Not sure if you are using AWS, but S3 could be a good choice for storing those then. You can access the files programatically or manually when needed.

Comment: Do you know what are the implication of storing it as a CLOB or BLOB? I don't know much about AWS and S3 but my team doesn't use AWS anyway.